# GIT checkout branch via terminal

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to checkout a branch using the command line (terminal on mac) knowing just:

```
ssh://git@dev.somename.se:8000/abc/somename.git
```

Comment: What's stopping you from trying it?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is done

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to clone this repository first using

```
git clone ssh://git@dev.somename.se:8000/abc/somename.git
```

This will be creating a local working copy of this project and will be on the default branch of it what is probably 'master'

You can verify which branch you are on using

```
git status
```

If you want a list of the available branches (in the remote repo) execute

```
git branch -r
```

If you want another remote branch available on your local copy you can use

```
git checkout --track origin/remotebranchname
```

The --track parameter will tie your local branch and remote branch together so you won't have to be give it explicitly when pushing your code for example.

Answer (score 1):

Create the branch on your local machine and switch in this branch :

```
$ git checkout -b [name_of_your_new_branch] [name_of_the_origin_branch]
```